# Manage dependency version centralized

Tags: maven

I've got multiple projects using a certain Dependency of Version `XX`, if I release a  new version, I have to touch every project to change it to version `XX.Y`.

I've came across an approach to edit my `m2` settings `<version>${my.version}</version>`, to add a parameter and bind it into my `POM.xml`, but this implicit means, *every*user has to manage their `m2` settings when I do a new release.

Is there a way to central (user independant) manage the versions as in SVN, so none has to change anything and it always uses the up2date version, if I release a new version?

Comment: The last part is a contradiction cause your users decide to use a different version which means they have to change something in their pom files which should be committed in version control (SVN etc.)...

Comment: @khmarbaise they don't decide, some people are lazy or miss to adapt the pom - my question is how to automatize it, so I (globally) set the version, check it in, and this will be taken for every *subproject*

Comment: I see your pain that people tend to forget to update. But smuggling version numbers into other projects may cause a lot of trouble as well (suddenly breaking projects without someone noticing). I am currently thinking about a deprecation mechanism but I haven't made up my mind yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pattern called "Bill of Material".

I think your question is somehow similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49559662/2129801) (but not exactly a duplicate), and my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49564020/2129801) applies here aswell:

> You create a new maven project (the bill of material) that only consists of a pom with dependency management block. Here you declare all your dependencies and their versions. The packaging should be set to `pom`.
>
> This bill of material (bom) project is now used as parent of all other projects. When using a dependency, only group id and artifact id is specified, the version tag is ommited. In that way, the version will be taken from the bom and you have one central place to manage the versions of the dependencies.
>
> More details with examples are [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) (in the lower part of the page) or [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-maven-bom).

Comment: For your BOM approach: Can I also specify in the bom the `<build>` process, because there I also see redundancies within the *subprojects*

Comment: I don't think this solves the problem, it only eases the pain because instead of multiple versions to change their is only one.

Comment: @0x2E5 yes this is possible. For example, the [jboss parent poms](https://github.com/jboss/jboss-parent-pom/blob/master/pom.xml) use this approach.

Comment: @JFMeier I think this leads eventually to the solution you described in your other comment, a multi-module project.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the maintainer of every project should decide for themselves if they update the version or not. Updating the version might break things, so they may choose to stay on the older version. Particularly, it is important that the maintainers *notice* that something has changed, so that tests are run.

For development, though, there are Snapshot versions. A Snapshot dependency always references the newest version, but the `-SNAPSHOT` indicates this to the maintainer of the project. Snapshot versions should not go to production - the builds are not reproducible.

If artifacts are so tightly coupled that they are build together, think about using multi module projects.

Comment: I manage this project and there are users. When I, and only if verified the new version is valid, I would commit it and want to force *every* user to take the new Version. Regardless *snapshots*.

Comment: Conceptually, the only Maven solution I see for your problem is to put your project and all subprojects into one multi-module project. Then you build everything together and all subprojects get the newest versions. Alternatively, you could run the versions plugin before every build to update the versions in the pom.